# zend framework 2 Authentication with mysqli fail

Tags: mysqli, zend-framework2, zend-auth, mysqli-multi-query

I have followed the zend instructions for implement my web Authentication using a database table with Mysqli driver configured.

When render the page, the following exceptions appears after execute authenticate method:

```
    Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\ErrorException
    File:
    C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Statement.php:188
    Mensaje:
    Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

It seems to be that it happen because the driver don't can execute multiples querys without free the results of the previous query first (multiquery problem).

I discovered that if changed the driver of the dbAdapter to pdo_mysql, authenticate method works ok. But I don't want use PDO drivers by performance reasons.

How I configure the Mysqli driver for can do it?

My code bellow:

```
    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(array(
        //'driver' => 'Mysqli',   //This driver fail when call authenticate method
        'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',  //This driver works ok
        'database' => 'securedraw',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => ''
    ));     
    $authAdapter = new AuthDbTableAdapter($dbAdapter);
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('mail')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setIdentity('josep')
                ->setCredential('josep');
    $authResult = $authAdapter->authenticate();   //Method fail
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure what the problem is is that you are mixing up the ways execute the query.  So what you have is for a PDO call and to use MySQLi you need to do

```
$dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(array(
   'driver' => 'Mysqli',   //This driver fail when call authenticate method
    'database' => 'securedraw',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => ''
));     
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);

$adapter->query("QUERY HERE");
```

I would reference this page here https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html as I am trying to learn how to do this myself